# Location-dependent vim settings

Tags: vim, macvim

I work on multiple software projects that have different style conventions. Is it possible for vim to automatically change its settings (e.g. indentation) depending on the directory a particular file lives in?

Comment: Sure, but it'll take a bit of scripting in your vimrc.

Comment: You might take a look at `:h 'exrc'` which enables per directory vimrc files

Answer (score 3):

### No

Vim doesn't have any settings appropriate for what's described.

### But there's a plugin for that

However, you may find a plugin that does what you want for example [vim-independence](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3887):

> The plugin is automatic, if the file .vimrc exists in your git project root - it will load it.

(full disclosure: I wrote that script)

Answer (score 1):

you can create some file with settings in each project. `.vim_setting` for example. and append `source .vim_settings` to your `.vimrc`. if you run vim from project directory, settings will be picked up